# Percentage for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, percentage

I have got an excel sheet, from which I need to make an Python function defining what the percentage of the "Go's" are located in the Motion row.
The Motion row has 16 (go's) and 4 (stops) which makes a total of 20.

I came up with this python code but it won't function as needed

```
if Motion = 20:
       Go = FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "16")
       Stop = FormSet.GetFieldValue(CurrentForm, "4")
       delta = float(20 - 16) / 100
       print( '( (go) are what percentage of the field [motion]: ', acount)))
```

I'm really really struggling. It would be really nice if someone could help me with it.

Comment: Your code is not valid Python (it is missing a colon after `if Motion = 20`). Is that a typo on your part?

Comment: Also `acount` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @Nomz You had tried to upload an image.. Try hosting it somewhere else, like someplace [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=free+image+hosting) and posting a  link to it in the question

Comment: You are not using Go or Stop or delta. What is account?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 80%.

For Python 3:

```
>>> a=16
>>> b=4
>>> (a/(a+b))*100
80.0
```

For Python 2:

```
>>> a=16
>>> b=4
>>> (a/float(a+b))*100
80.0
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a typo:

```
if Motion = 20
```

or you really mean to do this:

```
if Motion == 20:
```

Other than this I don´t see any obvious mistakes (except that I don't get what you are trying to print)